# How to write a custom filter function on Bootstrap Vue Table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I want to custom filter function on Bootstrap Vue Table. I didn't know what to write to the filter-function prop. I want to search filter.

```
<template>
<div>
<input
          @input.native="tableSearchDebounce"
          :input-class="history ? 'mb-0' : null"
          :form-group-class="history ? 'mb-0' : null"
          v-if="!history" />
<input
          v-model="filterTableInputSearchHistory"
          :input-class="history ? 'mb-0' : null"
          :form-group-class="history ? 'mb-0' : null"
          v-else />


 <b-table
        :items="items"
        :fields="fields"
        :filter="!history ? filterTableInputSearch : filterTableInputSearchHistory"
        @filtered="onFiltered"
      />

</div>
</template>
```

My methods :

```
    tableSearchDebounce(value) {
      clearTimeout(this.$_debounceTimer)
        this.$_debounceTimer = this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.filterTableInputSearch = value.target._value;
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-sort-compare-routine)

> You can provide your own custom sort compare routine by passing a function reference to the prop sort-compare. The sort-compare routine is passed seven (7) arguments, of which the last 4 are optional:

> - the first two arguments (a and b) are the record objects for the rows being compared
> - the third argument is the field key being sorted on (sortBy)
> - the fourth argument (sortDesc) is the order  will be displaying the records (true for descending, false for ascending)

You can then write your own sort function using those arguments.

Example :

```js
function sortCompare(aRow, bRow, key, sortDesc) {
  const a = aRow[key] // or use Lodash `_.get()`
  const b = bRow[key]
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
}
```

*Note : In this example, the `sortDesc` option is not used.*

---

You can then pass the function through the `sort-compare` options of the table

```
<b-table striped hover :items="items" :sort-compare="sortCompare"></b-table>
```

---

#Edit

It seems like you want to search filter using an input and so filter the elements that match the input.

In my opinion, the simplest way to do this would be to use a `computed property` to return only the elements that match the input.

This can be done by :

Adding a v-model to the input

```js
<input type="text" v-model="search" />
```

Creating a computed variable to search for the value you want to filter

```js
computed: {
   recordsFiletered() {
      return this.records.filter((record) => {
        return record.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
}
```

Or you can loop through all of the values of the object if you want to make it generic.

```js
recordsFiletered() {
      return this.records.filter((record) => {
        return Object.values(record).some((value) =>
          value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        );
      });
    },
```

*Note: This function does not search for property inside of an object*

Binding the computed variable to the table

```
<b-table :items="recordsFiletered"></b-table>
```

SandBox example: [Link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-vue-b-table-sort-select-issue-forked-nx4sbc?file=/src/components/GridTest.vue)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I want to search filter.

Comment: I've update my answer, please tee me if it it was you're looking for

Comment: Thanks a lot again but I just don't want to search for names. I would be very happy if you could make a search for all fields. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can loop through the properties of you object and check if one matches.